# Increase maximum UserName length in a custom ASP.Net Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using the membership provider with ASP.NET. The maximum length of a UserName is 50.
Is there a way to increase it?

I've already tried to increase the column size in the db but MemberShip.CreateUser fails for long usernames with a ProviderError

Comment: Alter the database column size, you basically can adapt it to anything your needs are

Comment: @Dalorzo It's not enough, there is a control somewhere

Comment: @SylvainBiehler: where? In you gui? What controls you use, custom controls or built-in controls? Your question lacks these details.

Comment: Dalorzo Quiestion updated

Comment: Which MembershipProvider exactly? it's an abstract class so implementation depends from the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can always override the UserName property, and specify the StringLength through DataAnnotations.  By default, this would be in your IdentityModel.cs file.

Add this line to your `ApplicationUser`class:

```
[StringLength(80)]
public new string UserName {get;set;}
```

I just ran a test and created a User with a 70 character-length string.

Answer (score 0):

> Increase maximum UserName length in a **custom** ASP.Net Membership

Your custom membership provider should implement `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` (see [MembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)). This has a method that you have to override:

```
public abstract MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

This is where you must implement your own validation of the method parameters including the allowable length of the incoming parameters. You can see the built in code for `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider` as an example which validates the username length to be no greater than 128 unicode characters.

So you will have to do 2 things.

1. In your database schema increase the username table field length to the correct maximum allowable size.
2. In your custom ASP.Net Membership provider (your class that inherits from `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`) alter the validation in the `CreateUser` method so that you check on the correct maximum allowed number of characters.

If you are not sure what class of yours is implementing `MembershipProvider` you can either search for code files for that string OR you can look in your `web.config` file here to get the type.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="providerName" >
      <providers>
        <add name="providerName" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
```

Code snipit from `SqlMembershipProvider`

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
  if (!SecUtility.ValidateParameter(ref password, true, true, false, 128)) // check on 128 maximum length
  {
    status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
    return (MembershipUser) null;
  }
```